# Intel Alder Lake-N100 wifi and bluetooth issues

Tags: iwlwifi

I need your help with setup wifi on my mini-PC.
CPU Intel N100, that includes wifi. default winOs had seen wifi and worked well.
I've already tried ubuntu 22.04 and 22.10, tried to install `backport-iwlwifi-dkms`, copied `iwlwifi` files from kernel linux github to `/lib/firmware`, upgraded kernel...
OS doesn't see wifi at all and bluetooth is not switching ON.

So everything what i found already - didn't help me.

```
# dmesg | grep iwlwifi
[    2.573402] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[    2.586226] iwlwifi: No config found for PCI dev 54f0/0244, rev=0x370, rfid=0x10c000
[    2.586247] iwlwifi: probe of 0000:00:14.3 failed with error -22


# uname -r
6.2.7-060207-generic


# rfkill list

0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no


# lspci -kvnn | sed -n '/Network/,/^$/ p'
00:14.3 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:54f0]
    DeviceName: Onboard - Ethernet
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device [8086:0244]
    Flags: fast devsel, IRQ 16
    Memory at 6001114000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: [c8] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [d0] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
    Capabilities: [40] Express Root Complex Integrated Endpoint, MSI 00
    Capabilities: [80] MSI-X: Enable- Count=16 Masked-
    Capabilities: [100] Latency Tolerance Reporting
    Capabilities: [164] Vendor Specific Information: ID=0010 Rev=0 Len=014 <?>
    Kernel modules: iwlwifi
```

[UPDATE]

found [this](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/drivers/net/wireless/intel/iwlwifi/cfg/22000.c#L515) - sounds promising.
Also found few [requests](https://community.intel.com/t5/Wireless/Where-to-get-Linux-driver-for-Intel-Wi-Fi-6-AX101/td-p/1457117) on intel community about support Linux, as it's promised on specs page.
will update mine findings here

[UPDATE 2023/04/04]
[intel community](https://community.intel.com/t5/Wireless/AX101-Ubuntu-22-04-or-22-10-driver/m-p/1473073/highlight/true#M46650) couldn't provide the support and forwarded to kernel.org :(

Comment: These problems can finally be solved now. Wifi works if you update to latest linux kernel and firmware. Bluetooth: https://www.reddit.com/r/NixOS/comments/17z0p46/howto_drive_bluetooth_on_12th_gen_intel_ax101/ Not tested on Ubuntu, though :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a bug of ax101 driver, and unfortunately still not fixed in the latest kernel 6.3-rc5.

I can connect to WIFI5 AP after applying following patch .
linux 6.1.20

```
--- a/drivers/net/wireless/intel/iwlwifi/pcie/drv.c       2023-04-04 10:22:33.957021791 +0800
+++ b/drivers/net/wireless/intel/iwlwifi/pcie/drv.c       2023-04-04 11:51:37.377716152 +0800
@@ -1091,7 +1091,7 @@
        _IWL_DEV_INFO(IWL_CFG_ANY, IWL_CFG_ANY,
                      IWL_CFG_MAC_TYPE_SO, IWL_CFG_ANY,
                      IWL_CFG_RF_TYPE_HR1, IWL_CFG_ANY,
-                     IWL_CFG_160, IWL_CFG_ANY, IWL_CFG_NO_CDB, IWL_CFG_ANY,
+                     IWL_CFG_ANY, IWL_CFG_ANY, IWL_CFG_NO_CDB, IWL_CFG_ANY,
                      iwl_cfg_so_a0_hr_a0, iwl_ax101_name),
        _IWL_DEV_INFO(IWL_CFG_ANY, IWL_CFG_ANY,
                      IWL_CFG_MAC_TYPE_SO, IWL_CFG_ANY,
@@ -1108,7 +1108,7 @@
        _IWL_DEV_INFO(IWL_CFG_ANY, IWL_CFG_ANY,
                      IWL_CFG_MAC_TYPE_SOF, IWL_CFG_ANY,
                      IWL_CFG_RF_TYPE_HR1, IWL_CFG_ANY,
-                     IWL_CFG_160, IWL_CFG_ANY, IWL_CFG_NO_CDB, IWL_CFG_ANY,
+                     IWL_CFG_ANY, IWL_CFG_ANY, IWL_CFG_NO_CDB, IWL_CFG_ANY,
                      iwl_cfg_so_a0_hr_a0, iwl_ax101_name),
        _IWL_DEV_INFO(IWL_CFG_ANY, IWL_CFG_ANY,
                      IWL_CFG_MAC_TYPE_SOF, IWL_CFG_ANY,
```

But it would still failed to connect to WIFI 6 AP due to firmware error, so you must disable 802.11ax when loading driver :

```shell
modprobe iwlwifi disable_11ax=true
```

or write `options iwlwifi disable_11ax=true` to /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf and `update-initramfs -k all -u` to make it persistent.

Another bad news is bluetooth still not works due to lack of firmware ibt-0040-1050.sfi:

```
[    3.702448] Bluetooth: hci0: Minimum firmware build 1 week 10 2014
[    3.702449] Bluetooth: hci0: Bootloader timestamp 2019.40 buildtype 1 build 38
[    3.704410] bluetooth hci0: firmware: failed to load intel/ibt-0040-1050.sfi (-2)
[    3.704440] bluetooth hci0: firmware: failed to load intel/ibt-0040-1050.sfi (-2)
[    3.704452] Bluetooth: hci0: Failed to load Intel firmware file intel/ibt-0040-1050.sfi (-2)
[    4.053680] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
```

Comment: A this is both an unsupported kernel and a kernel that is still under development this is not an answer.

Comment: Thank you for you comment!
by the official answer from intel is https://community.intel.com/t5/Wireless/AX101-Ubuntu-22-04-or-22-10-driver/m-p/1473073/highlight/true#M46650 - I need to look for help on kernel side, and it doesn't matter that on specs AX101 has Linux support.

Comment: hey @zhu-hai, could you please help me - how to apply your patch?

Answer (score 1):

Zhu hai patch looks correct.  It is similar to the Arch patch which definitely works on 6.2.x kernels.
https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/iwlwifi-ax101-dkms

I have tested a workaround for the blutooth issue.
Rename the files ...

```
/usr/lib/firmware/intel/ibt-1040-4150.ddc.xz
/usr/lib/firmware/intel/ibt-1040-4150.sfi.xz
```

to

```
/usr/lib/firmware/intel/ibt-1040-1050.ddc.xz
/usr/lib/firmware/intel/ibt-1040-1050.sfi.xz
```

The 1040-4150 fw is for an earlier version of the AX201 bluetooth usb.

I've listened to BT audio and played w/ several BT devices this way.  No promises.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: There is actually a cleaner fix to this I posted in a separate but related thread: https://askubuntu.com/a/1492845/978235

Answer (score 0):

The device appeared in your lspci output:
Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device [8086:0244]

That is the Intel AX101, which was only released in Q3'22:
https://www.intel.ca/content/www/ca/en/products/sku/203014/intel-wifi-6-ax101/specifications.html

It is possible that your device does not yet have Linux support. Support might come in a future kernel.

Comment: I agree entirely and I suggest that you report a bug: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs

Comment: thank you @thewade and @chili555!
Does it mean that next year I will need to use ethernet?(( 
I couldn't find how to request new driver support in ubuntu-help, there are only about bugs.((
PS. is it possible to start PC without monitor nowadays? or I need dummy hmdi?

Comment: I think it is a bug not a lack of support. Looking into the iwlwifi driver I see references to the AX101. 

However this commit removed the device ID from its PCI list so I have no idea how it could possibly map the device to the driver:
https://github.com/torvalds/linux/commit/3f910a25839b13436bf0a22186f1698b23eafb91

You can try reporting the bug to Ubuntu, or directly against the kernel at https://bugzilla.kernel.org/

If it is a simple as adding the device ID it might be quick to fix.

Comment: There are any number of supported out of the box USB wireless devices; please check here: https://github.com/morrownr/USB-WiFi

Comment: thank you all! lost in tabs. and duplicated some info - sorry about.

Comment: found another [opened issue](https://community.intel.com/t5/Wireless/AX101-Linux-driver/m-p/1465559#M46101) on intel community, looks pretty fresh. I will try to follow it, give them chance ) fingers crossed.

Comment: I would add this relevent message to your Intel community post: "No config found for PCI dev 54f0/0244, rev=0x370, rfid=0x10c000"

Comment: Thanks @chili555! Great idea! I will do! Also will leave the reference to this topic.