# Ubuntu 22.04 not connecting to one specific wifi network

Tags: drivers, wireless, 22.04, password

I have bought a new miniPC and installed Ubuntu 22.04 on it.
It has an Alder Lake n100 processor with wifi adapter AX101 and wifi was not working at all as system was not recognising it. After some investigation I found here the solution to my problems:
[Add the lastest intel ax201 wireless firmware work on Ubuntu 20.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1404944/add-the-lastest-intel-ax201-wireless-firmware-work-on-ubuntu-20-04?newreg=0d947f18dceb4a69b29b07e0ad1ecb5a)

I applied the fix suggested and wifi&bluetooth were working... But I cannot connect to my home wifi.

Wifi network is found and signal excelent (100%).

It is always trying to connect and asking for connection key. Of course I have checked one hundred times the password is the correct one. I have many other devices at home connected to same router and all of them working with same password. I have tried to change password and all working except Ubuntu machine. I have changed security protocol in router and still nothing. Set the connection with no security and Ubuntu still not connecting giving a connection error message...
There is no difference making the tests via user interface or via terminal, the result is the same.
Last test was to connect Ubuntu to a hotspot on my phone and Ubuntu is connecting and accessing internet, so the driver and firmware issue seems to be really solved, but I have not clue why I cannot access to my home wifi.

My router is a ZTE F6640 just in case it means something to anyone, but again, this has been working (and still is) without any issue with all the phones, ipads, laptops and any other gadget using wifi at home. Even with an old laptop running with ubuntu 20.04 there is no issue.

I don't know what else to try or to check.
Anyone any hint?

EDIT: Solved with the hint provided here:
[Can't connect to specific wifi network](https://askubuntu.com/questions/286915/cant-connect-to-specific-wifi-network?rq=1)
Finally it is a hardware uncompatibility issue, but solved with a set up change