Kubuntu 24.04 Intel Wireless AX201 adapter not showing on fresh install
Installed 24.04 on available partition
Smooth install
On boot up network adapter not found, so not connecting to network
Adapter is Intel AX201 which is supported in this version
Lots of similar issues seen when researching this issue

Ok, after looking at lots of advice, I tried something different that did not require 10 different gyrations.
Shut down system.
At Grub select Advanced.
Select Recovery mode.
Go to Network and tell the system to turn it on.
Go to option to check system, let it do so.
Go to option to repair and let that run.
Now resume boot.
Check wireless, and see if you now have an adapter showing and can see networks.
If so, when you connect, it might jump and down a bit at first
Be patient.
Once stable on 2.4 or 5GHz, flip to the other one, so both are setup.
Once stable again, reboot.
If successful you should now be able to connect to your network without trying to reload a driver.
Note: this was for Intel AX201 card that shows support in Kernels 5.4 and later.

Other related Answers: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1495421/trying-to-get-the-ax201-wifi-card-working , https://askubuntu.com/questions/1404944/add-the-lastest-intel-ax201-wireless-firmware-work-on-ubuntu-20-04 . https://askubuntu.com/questions/1352653/intel-ax201-wi-fi-6-is-not-working-on-ubuntu-21-04 .

As Ubuntu 24.04 uses a 6.8 kernel I do not see how this answer is of any value?

I listed the Minimum kernal not the max, that the driver is designed for. The value is in not having to find another way to get network connection, i.e. not having to load from another device or use alternate connection like recommended in other posts.
